# Spanish for "link"

Tags: vocabulario, diferencias-regionales, dialectos

While listening to a podcast from SpanishPod recently, I came across this section where they were discussing the Spanish for various computer-related terms and one of the hosts gave **liga** as the Spanish for **link**, the stuff that when clicked leads to a different web page.

Elsewhere, I have also heard two other words for the same term: **vínculo** and **enlace**. Do all three really mean the exact same thing? I want to know if there's any, just any, difference among the three whatsoever. Any subtle difference?

And if they are all really the same thing, which is the preferred word in which region? Which of the three is preferred in Mexico? What about other parts of the world?

Comment: Vínculo, that evil word from Microsoft...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In México we can use **vínculo** or **enlace** but it is more common to use **liga**.

The later is used in a day to day conversation, vínculo and enlace are more formal.

By the way... **ligar** as a verb is used here when referring to *flirting*.

```
 ¿Cuál es la liga para comprar esa bolsa en ebay?

 Pásame la liga para entrar a tu sitio.
```

Answer (score 7):

The original meaning of *link*, IIUIC, is *each of the rings of a chain*. That is Spanish is *eslabón*. (cf. *The missing link* / *El eslabón perdido*).

Then, in English, *link* is also used to mean *connection* or even *relation*. That, in Spanish, would be *conexión*, *enlace* or *relación*.

In Internet language, *link* is actually a short form of the original *hyperlink* (remember that HTTP stands for *HyperText Transfer Protocol*). That was usually translated as *hiper-enlace* or *hiper-vínculo* (with or without dashes). Then, when the English form shortened to *link* Spanish followed suit and, therefore, today we use *enlace* or *vínculo*.

As a new meaning for an old word, I don't think that *vínculo* is better than *enlace* or vice versa. Personally, I prefer *enlace*. It just sounds better to me (but I'm from Spain).

However, about the other word you comment, *liga*, I think it is used solely because it sounds similar to the English one, so it may be best to refrain from using it. *Ligar* means *tie* or *bind*, only somewhat similar to *link*.

Comment: I agree enlace is really the only thing that works, but vínculo makes sense as well.

Comment: @CayetanoGonçalves: The thing is that _enlace_ sounds nice, but the older _hiperenlace_ sounds a bit weird to Spanish ears, maybe because of the syllabification: it would be natural to do it as _hi-pe-ren-la-ce_, but the speaker tries to keep the prefix separated as _hi-per--en-la-ce_. _Hipervínculo_ does not have this issue so it may have been preferred in the early days of Internet.

Comment: However, liga is not correctly understood in some places. But I think "vínculo" and "enlace" are understood even in places where it hasn't this meaning (but the original).

Comment: It's important to keep in mind that "ligar" mean to bond and in some places is related to "paste". So, it would be confusing because "paste" has another meaning in computer jerga.

Comment: @ESL: Also "ligar" in some places means "pick up", as in "seek a casual romantic relationship", so if you use it carelessly you can get some funny looks.

Answer (score 4):

Here in Chile, we say *link*, *vínculo* or *enlace*.

Answer (score 3):

Link, in the meaning you describe, is indistinctly translated in Spain and Mexico as **vínculo** or **enlace**.
There are no nuances when using one or the other, so probably is a matter of habitude in using one or the other.
For example, Microsoft uses **vínculo** exclusively for their software localized in Spanish from Spain (es_es), and **vínculo** or **enlace**, depending of the package, when in Spanish from Mexico (es_mx). However, **enlace** is as widely used as **vínculo** in Spain.

[Source](http://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=link&langID=es-es)

Comment: Though, looking to Microsoft for translations is probably not the best idea.  They after all translated English _font_ as _fuente_ (_tipografía_ or _tipo_ being the words actually used by typographers) and refuse to fix it even after I've reported it many times.

Comment: Yes, that's true, they used to use "mouse" as spanish translation for "mouse". But the fact is that sometimes the wide use of a translation makes it more understandable; even bad uses of words have become accepted because of its wide use. Think of the use of "incierto" as synonym for "false" (which is incorrect as "incierto" means "uncertain"), widely used by spanish politicians as a more politically correct way to say "falso". Finally, "incierto" is now accepted by the Real Academia Española de la Lengua as synonym for "false".

Answer (score 1):

The three words are exatly the same, but **enlace** and **vínculo** are for the formal speech and text while **liga** and **link** are the "informal" ones but ther's no problem for using both words in formal talking. Personally I've never said **liga**, me and my environment use **link**. I'm from México.

1. That's the link.
2. Ese es el enlace.
3. Ese es el vínculo.
4. Esa es la liga.
5. Ese es el link.