# Link or enlace?

Tags: gramática

I'm translating a page from pt-br to es-cl and in portuguese we refer to "link" as "link" because "ligação" is considered a big word to be repeated too much and in pt-br there are not many strict rules about translations so usually English words are kept en-us as long as everybody understands.

During the translation work, I found out some countries have more strict rules about translation (like in Portugal, which almost everything have to be translated, no English words at all).

So, for the translations, should i keep "link" or "enlace" or "liga" or anything else for the matter?

Comment: Relacionada: [spanish for link](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/6948/spanish-for-link)

Comment: My friend Concha Perea illustrated the [drawbacks of using "link"](https://twitter.com/PereaConcha/status/1131137006573096960) in Spanish. :-)

Comment: Of course im asking "when translating to Spanish" i just used the portuguese translation rule as a EXAMPLE.

Answer (score 2):

Most programs in Spanish use either **vínculo** or **enlace**, with the latter being the most common at this point.

You may hear *link* occasionally but I don't think anyone would expect to see it written out in a program generally.

Comment: also the "hyper" counterpart "hipervinculo" and "hiperenlace"

Answer (score 0):

I will consider you are talking about an informatic text to be translated, so I think you could use **link** with no problem; most of people involved in this area understand the word. However, you could use *enlace* more than *vínculo* to translate it. I thought you could use *liga*, but no definition of *liga* in DRAE fits to the link concept.

> [vínculo](https://dle.rae.es/?id=bqStQuu)
>
> Del lat. vincŭlum.
>
> 1. m. Unión o atadura de una persona o cosa con otra. U. m. en sent. fig.
> 2. m. Der. Sujeción de los bienes, con prohibición de enajenarlos, a que sucedan en ellos los parientes por el orden que señala el fundador, o al sustento de institutos benéficos u obras pías. Se usa también hablando del conjunto de bienes adscritos a una vinculación.
> 3. m. Inform. [enlace](https://dle.rae.es/?id=FTVRKyj) (‖ secuencia de caracteres).

Real Academia Española © Todos los derechos reservados

> [enlace](https://dle.rae.es/?id=FTVRKyj)
>
> 1. m. Acción de enlazar.
> 2. m. Unión, conexión de algo con otra cosa.
> 3. m. Conjunto de dos o más letras bordadas o grabadas en objetos de uso normal, generalmente las iniciales de los nombres de los propietarios.
> 4. m. En los trenes, empalme.
> 5. m. Casamiento o boda.
> 6. m. Inform. Secuencia de caracteres que se utiliza como dirección para acceder a información adicional en un mismo o distinto servidor.
> 7. m. Quím. Unión de dos átomos en un compuesto químico.
> 8. m. y f. Persona que establece o mantiene relación entre otras, especialmente dentro de alguna organización.

Real Academia Española © Todos los derechos reservados